# Receiving "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused error" in Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am working on my Mac and i am trying to connect to database as shown in the env file i have mention the db name but i still getting this error on my laravel project. i have tried it on core php project it work but i get this error while connecting laravel project to database.

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cart and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE') at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671

```
667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670|         catch (Exception $e) {
671|             throw new QueryException(
672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
673|             );
674|         }
675|
```

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
php artisan config:clear
```

and then

```
php artisan migrate
```

that if you are sure the database already exists

Comment: i have tried this many times but no success. and after running this i get this....SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = cart and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

Comment: @ahmedayoub please create new database and make sure the name is correct , and user and password .